# Weird leak when using [NSStringObject UTF8String]

Tags: objective-c

I have this function:

```
-(void) debugPrint
{
    printf("name: %s", [_name UTF8String]);
}
```

This results in a runtime error:

[Session started at 2009-03-21 15:02:26 -0700.]
2009-03-21 15:02:26.319 TGui[20063:10b] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10a290 of class NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x9234c73f 0x92258e32 0x9226d505 0x9226d0e1 0x2406 0x22ce 0x20be)
name: name

What's weird is that when I do [_name cString], it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The thread on which you call that method doesn't have an `NSAutoreleasePool`, so autoreleased objects have no pool. You have to set up an `NSAutoreleasePool` for each thread. The intro for the [`NSAutoreleasePool`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation explains this idea in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops--I was putting the all to debugPrint in main(), before the call to "return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **) argv);". This was causing problems.